# Бизнес-классики, реализация задачи

Tags: c, c++

Доброго времени суток, прошу помощи по решению задачи,а именно в помощи написанию реализации, мне не ясно:
 Каким образом можно собрать максимальное кол-во денег(есть ли какой-то алгоритм по проходу матрицы который позволит это осуществить),можно ли пройти матрицу с помощью комбинации вертикальной и горизонтальной змейки? если да, то каким образом нужно построить алгоритм чтобы он гарантированно находил решение?

**Задача следующая:**
Поле для игры в бизнес-классики представляет собой прямоугольник, состоящий из 3 * N клеток. В некоторых клетках лежит по одному рублю, в остальных - ничего нет. Играющий выбирает для начала игры одну из трех левых клеток и прыгает в нее. За один ход играющий перепрыгивает в одну из клеток, имеющих общую сторону с той, в которой он находится. При этом запрещено прыгать в те клетки, в которых он уже побывал. При очередном прыжке все деньги, собранные к этому моменту, удваиваются, а затем, если в новой клетке лежит рубль, то он прибавляется к имеющейся сумме денег. Считается, что в начале игры денег у играющего нет. Закончить прыжки надо в одной из трех правых клеток поля и при этом заработать как можно больше денег.

Требуется написать программу, которая по известному значению N и расположению рублей в клетках находит такую последовательность прыжков, при которой играющий заработает наибольшее количество денег. Если таких последовательностей несколько, то следует выбрать любую последовательность, количество прыжков в которой минимально.

**Входные данные:**
В первой строке входного файла с именем CLASS.IN записано натуральное число N (1 < N < 80). В каждой из последующих трех строк находится N чисел (0 или 1), описывающих расположение рублей в клетках первой, второй и третьей строки игрового поля соответственно. Единица обозначает наличие рубля в клетке, ноль - его отсутствие. Числа в каждой из этих трех строк входного файла расположены через пробел.

**Выходные данные:**
Выходной файл с именем CLASS.OUT должен содержать 2 строки. В первой строке должен находиться номер строки игрового поля (1, 2 или 3), с которой играющему следует начать игру. Вторая строка файла должна описывать последовательность прыжков. Каждый прыжок в этой последовательности нужно обозначить одним из следующих символов:

U - если в результате прыжка номер строки, на которой находится играющий, уменьшился на 1;
D - если номер строки увеличился на 1;
L - если номер столбца уменьшился на 1;
R - если номер столбца увеличился на 1.

Символы во второй строке выходного файла должны быть выведены без пробелов.

**Пример входного файла:**

```
4
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

Пример выходного файла для приведенного примера входного файла:

```
 1
 DDRUURDDRUU
```

Comment: @Igor  Zimenko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: ну вообще это не похоже на задачу для учащихся, а скорее на олимпиадную задачу. причем хорошей такой олимпиады. мне, например, интересно было бы увидеть решение такой задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как за каждый ход деньги удваиваются, то нужно пройти все клетки (чтобы максимизировать прибыль). То есть это просто обход графа. Стартовая клетка - одна с трех, конечная - также одна с трех, поэтому можно рассматривать девять пар клеток - девять вариантов.

Для дальнейшей максимизации денег нужно выбирать такой маршрут, в котором единички встречаются раньше.

Переведем это на программерский язык. Пусть у каждого маршрута есть его  "трек", то есть просто запись содержимого текущих клеток. Для примера выше это будет просто 111111111100.  Самый "прибыльный маршрут тот, у которого двоичное представление будет больше (да, сравнивать как обычные двоичные числа). Это достаточно легко доказать, если увидеть, что описание сбора денег описывает классический алгоритм перевода с двоичной системы счисления в десятичную.

То есть алгоритм простой - для каждой из девяти начальных пар находим все возможные пути обхода таблицы, которые покрывают максимум клеток, потом находим максимальный трек.

Алгоритм поиска трека также прост. С начальной ячейки рекурсивно бежим в каждую сторону, если больше бежать некуда - проверяем, в последнем ли ряду. Если да - сверяем маршрут, если нет, отбрасываем. Если этот алгоритм закодировать правильно, то пар на самом деле будет не девять, а просто три начальные точки. :)

Comment: То есть, алгоритм поиска трека можно сравнить с алгоритмом Поиска в глубину в графе, только тут мы начинаем с клеток справа и для каждой клетки рекурсивно движемся по смежным клеткам и по ходу записываем нули и единички и из найденных решений выбираем максимальное?

Comment: ну да. Посмотрел ещё раз на задачу - можно ещё ускорить - как только набрали 2-3 вершины, можно сравнивать найденое начало с началом максимума. И можно очень быстро отсекать заведомо плохие варианты. Единственно, что вначале нужно найти максимально длинный путь. А это сделать достаточно просто (он будет такой. два вниз, один вправо, два вверх, один влево, повторять до конца).